# Will CPU-bound work stay on thread pool thread when using nested async-await?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task, threadpool

This might be a somewhat trivial question, but I want to make sure that I am not missing any detail here.

I have the following code, where `OnButtonClick` ist invoked by the UI-Thread:

```
async void OnButtonClick()
{
    await Task.Run(DoWork);
}

static async Task DoWork()
{
    // Do Something
    // Do something else
    await DoSubWork();
    // Do yet another thing
}

static async Task DoSubWork()
{
    DoCpuBoundWorkOne();
    await DoIOBoundWork();
    DoCpuBoundWorkTwo();
}

static void DoCpuBoundWorkOne()
{
    // Do something
}

static async Task DoIOBoundWork()
{
    // Do something
}

static void DoCpuBoundWorkTwo()
{
    // Do something
}
```

My two questions are:

1. Will the work inside `DoCpuBoundWorkTwo` still be executed on a thread pool thread?
2. Will this always be the same thread that has been started by `Task.Run` inside `OnButtonClick`, povided that there was no explicit `.ConfigureAwait(false)` call in between?

Comment: *["The async and await keywords don't cause additional threads to be created. Async methods don't require multithreading because an async method doesn't run on its own thread. The method runs on the current synchronization context and uses time on the thread only when the method is active. You can use Task.Run to move CPU-bound work to a background thread, but a background thread doesn't help with a process that's just waiting for results to become available."](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/asynchronous-programming/task-asynchronous-programming-model)*

Comment: One of the main points of using modern async models and tasks is to focus on the *task at hand*, not the *underlying mechanisms*. Why do you think it's so important *which* thread is running the work provided it's getting done? If the concern is "I'm using x, y, or z that has thread affinity" then the usual response is to find specific alternatives to those that don't have thread affinity or that are specifically async context aware

Comment: I do know that async/await don't create threads. I have also watched [The Matrix](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/there_is_no_spoon), erm, sorry I mean [this version](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html). The code snippet above is my attempt to boil down my question to a simple case. What I actually need to know is that the CPU-bound work is executed as "parallel" and isolated as possible. I am coming from [this broader question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75558013/how-to-create-and-start-long-running-tasks-dynamically-and-with-scoped-dependenc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will the work inside `DoCpuBoundWorkTwo` still be executed on a thread pool thread?

Most likely yes, with a very high probability. But it's not guaranteed.

> Will this always be the same thread that has been started by `Task.Run` inside `OnButtonClick`, provided that there was no explicit `.ConfigureAwait(false)` call in between?

Maybe, or maybe not. The likelihood of being the same thread depends on the size of the `ThreadPool` at that moment. The bigger the size of the pool, the less the probability is. For example if the [`ThreadPool.ThreadCount`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool.threadcount) is `2`, the probability is 50%. It'll be a coin flop. It'll be either the one thread or the other. As for the presence of `.ConfigureAwait(false)`, it shouldn't make much of a  difference.¹

As an example of how the `DoCpuBoundWorkTwo` could end-up running on a non-`ThreadPool` thread, see this asynchronous method:

```
static Task UnorthodoxMethodAsync()
{
    TaskCompletionSource tcs = new();
    new Thread(() => { Thread.Sleep(100); tcs.SetResult(); }).Start();
    return tcs.Task;
}
```

It returns a `Task` that completes on a newly created thread, after a small delay in order to ensure that the `await` will complete asynchronously. See what happens when you `await` this method:

```
await Task.Run(async () =>
{
    Console.WriteLine($"1. ThreadPool: {Thread.CurrentThread.IsThreadPoolThread}");
    await UnorthodoxMethodAsync();
    Console.WriteLine($"2. ThreadPool: {Thread.CurrentThread.IsThreadPoolThread}");
});
```

Output:

```
1. ThreadPool: True
2. ThreadPool: False
```

[Online demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/NHeUQz).

It is even possible for the `DoCpuBoundWorkTwo` to run on the UI thread, but doing so would require next level acrobatics. Basically the `UnorthodoxMethodAsync` would need a reference to the [`SynchronizationContext.Current`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.current) stored in the UI thread, and then do this:

```
static Task UnorthodoxMethodAsync()
{
    SynchronizationContext sc = GetUiSyncContext();
    TaskCompletionSource tcs = new();
    sc.Post(_ => { Thread.Sleep(100); tcs.SetResult(); }, null);
    return tcs.Task;
}
```

In general you shouldn't worry too much about these exotic scenarios. Personally I don't know of any asynchronous method in the standard .NET libraries that completes on non-`ThreadPool` threads, excluding some advanced TPL utility APIs like the `Task.Factory.StartNew` with the [`TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskcreationoptions) option.

¹ <sub>The `ThreadPool` threads are not equipped with a `SynchronizationContext` by default, and the `.ConfigureAwait(false)` has no effect when both the [`SynchronizationContext.Current`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.current) and [`TaskScheduler.Current`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.current) are `null`. The `Task.Run` changes the `TaskScheduler.Current` to the internal [`System.Threading.Tasks.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/ThreadPoolTaskScheduler.cs), which is captured by the `await`, but this scheduler is not picky when it comes to executing tasks inline. It executes them happily on whatever the current thread is.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

> Will the work inside DoCpuBoundWorkTwo still be executed on a thread pool thread?

Yes.

> Will this always be the same thread that has been started by Task.Run inside OnButtonClick, povided that there was no explicit .ConfigureAwait(false) call in between?

No, there is no guarantee that it will be the same thread. Note that Task.Run will probably not start a new thread, but use an existing one from the pool.

In most UI program there will be two different "context", the UI context and the thread pool context. So if you await some task on the UI thread you will continue on the UI thread. If you await something on a non UI thread you will continue on a thread pool thread. But that is mostly relevant if you are using some thread/task local storage.

Just make sure your program is thread safe whenever you are running anything on a background thread.

Comment: for first question, how come "yes"? Why cannot the same thread carry `DoCpuBoundWorkTwo` out?

Comment: @SonerfromTheOttomanEmpire It can. But since `DoSubWork` is run on a threadpool thread, then anything after await will also run on a threadpool thread. It may be the same thread or another thread, but in either case it will be a threadpool thread.