# How to create and start long running tasks dynamically and with scoped dependencies in ASP.NET 7 (no hosted service at compile time)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, async-await, dependency-injection, threadpool

I am using ASP.NET and would like to create and start long running tasks from inside any scoped service or singleton service or hosted service. Neither the number of the tasks nor the time when they should be created are known at compile time. Instead, either during an HTTP request handling or during some BackgroundService cycle the need for some heavy, mostly CPU-bound work (e.g. some simulation calculations) arises and that's when a number of long running tasks should be created on the thread pool.
Additionally the long running tasks should be able to consume scoped dependencies whose lifetime equals their own lifetime.

I came up with the following solution for a task starter:

```
public interface ILongRunningTaskStarter
{
    public void FireAndForget<TWorkDependencies>(Func<TWorkDependencies, CancellationToken, Task> longRunningWork) where TWorkDependencies : notnull;
}

public class LongRunningTaskStarter : ILongRunningTaskStarter
{
    protected readonly ILogger<LongRunningTaskStarter> _logger;
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
    private readonly CancellationTokenSource _stoppingCts  = new CancellationTokenSource();

    public LongRunningTaskStarter(ILogger<LongRunningTaskStarter> logger, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    private Func<CancellationToken, Task> WrapInScope<TWorkDependencies>(Func<TWorkDependencies, CancellationToken, Task> longRunningWork) where TWorkDependencies : notnull
    {
        return async (stoppingToken) =>
        {
            try
            {
                _logger.LogDebug("Long running task on Thread {ThreadId} has started.", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
                using var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope();
                var scopedDependencies = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<TWorkDependencies>();
                await longRunningWork(scopedDependencies, stoppingToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException)
            {
                _logger.LogDebug("Long running task on Thread {ThreadId} has stopped.", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
                throw;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError(ex, "Uncaught exception from long running task on Thread {ThreadId}.", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            }
        };
    }

    public void FireAndForget<TWorkDependencies>(Func<TWorkDependencies, CancellationToken, Task> longRunningWork) where TWorkDependencies : notnull
    {
        var stoppingToken = _stoppingCts.Token;
        var scopedWork = WrapInScope(longRunningWork);
        Task.Run(() => scopedWork(stoppingToken), stoppingToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}
```

It can be used from any scoped/singleton/hosted service like this:

```
public class SimulationExampleComponent : ISimulationExampleComponent
{
    private ILongRunningTaskStarter _taskStarter;

    public SimulationExampleComponent(ILongRunningTaskStarter taskStarter)
    {
        _taskStarter = taskStarter;
    }

    public async Task ExecuteAvailableSimulationJobs()
    {
        var simulationInputList = await RequestSimulationJobsFromServer();
        foreach (var simulationInput in simulationInputList)
        {
            var longRunningWork = (ISimulationDependencies dep, CancellationToken token) => Simulate(dep, token, simulationInput);
            _taskStarter.FireAndForget(longRunningWork);
        }
    }

    private static Task<double[]> RequestSimulationJobsFromServer()
    {
        var dummyInput = new Random().NextDoubleSequence().Take(100).ToArray();
        return Task.FromResult(dummyInput);
    }

    private static async Task Simulate(ISimulationDependencies dep, CancellationToken stoppingToken, double simulationInput)
    {
        // The real long running work goes here:
        //      1. Do whatever the simulation needs to simulate while sending out status events.
        //      2. Write the output to some data storage.
        //      3. Inform interested parties about the completed simulation.
    }
}
```

The type registration during startup looks like this:

```
services.AddScoped<ISimulationDependencies, SimulationDependencies>();
services.AddSingleton<ILongRunningTaskStarter, LongRunningTaskStarter>();
services.AddScoped<ISimulationExampleComponent, SimulationExampleComponent>();
```

Now I have five questions concerning the whole dependency injection and scope magic:

1. Is there any risk of a deadlock in the above code, especially when calling `scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<TWorkDependencies>()` inside the task starter?
2. Is there any risk of dependencies being disposed precociously in the above code? The `await` in `await longRunningWork` should make sure that the captured scope will not be disposed precociously, right?
3. Does the `.ConfigureAwait(false)` call make any difference in accessing the scope? Is the scope concept orthogonal to and independent of the thread context?
4. Could there be a problem with nested scopes (creating a scope within another scope) in the ASP.NET dependency injection framework behind the scenes? For example when the `SimulationExampleComponent` is created in scope A and then later creates a new scope B for the long running task via `_taskStarter.FireAndForget()`?
5. Is there a better way to achieve what I want to achieve? (I know there is a bit of service locator flavour to my solution. But then this is usually the case with [issues of this kind](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/scoped-service#rewrite-the-worker-class).)

Comment: I see 5 questions, but the biggest red flag to me is the fire-and-forget. Fire and forget means "I don't care if this completes"; are you sure that's the case here? Fire and forget work can be occasionally lost, with no logging to indicate it disappeared; are you sure that's what you want?

Comment: Regarding your first sentence, do you mean that as an advice to split this up in 5 SO-questions? I wanted to avoid copying&pasting the descriptions and code snippets, since the questions are related and kind of boil down to question 5 (and the title) anyway. Regarding your fire-and-forget question, I leave it to the long running tasks to communicate their status to interested parties by means of their injected dependencies, e.g. `ISimulationDependencies` can be used to report back to the server. Also, there's the stopping token for handling shutdown. So it is more of a fire-and-almost-forget.

Comment: I don't think splitting the questions up is necessary, but most people here prefer it. I'm not sure if you understood what I meant re fire-and-forget: with FAF, you cannot guarantee that the work will report progress or even have a chance to shutdown. There are situations where work done this way will just disappear.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying, Stephen. Do you have further details (maybe in your blog) about what you mean exactly? How can the work just disappear? If the author of such a long running task, i.e. of the `longRunningWork` function/lambda passed to `FireAndForget`, is making sure that said function sends out progress messages (e.g. via `HttpClient`), how could these messages then be swallowed by the system? Yes, the system as a whole might crash and then the progress that has not been reported up to that point, will be lost. But that's always the case with non-persistent data, isn't it?

Comment: The work will disappear any time the process exits, which can be for a wide variety of reasons. Including, e.g., updating the application code.
`But that's always the case with non-persistent data, isn't it?` Yes, which is exactly why [important work must be kept in durable storage](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2021/01/asynchronous-messaging-2-durable-queues.html).

Comment: Thanks for the further details. That's a risk I am willing to take, since I use the transactional outbox pattern in my code base and the work between two consecutive progress updates can be lost in the rare case of a shutdown.

Comment: Ok; if you already have the outbox pattern then you should be fine. There's a possibility of duplicate work, but for progress updates it probably won't matter.